# Django load static tag not showing image

Tags: html, django, django-templates

Tried viewing image on my browers but all i can see is the image placeholder.

Here is the template code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="POST" style="background-color: rgb(201, 201, 24); padding: 10px;">
            {% csrf_token %}
        
            {{ form.as_p }}
       
            <input type="submit" value="submit">
    
        </form>


        {% load static %}
        <img src="{% static 'myapp/mini.jpg}" alt="My image"/>
    
    
    </body>
</html>
```

in the settings i have:

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    'myapp/static',

]

STATIC_ROOT = 'static/'
```

What can be the issue?

I have tried renaming the folders and rearranging the image location but non helped.

Comment: Replace `"{% static 'myapp/mini.jpg}"` with `"{% static 'myapp/mini.jpg' %}"`

Answer (score 1):

Your static tag isn't closed, but also, `STATIC_ROOT` must be an absolute path to a directory where `collectstatic` can copy all the static files to.

So typically you'll have settings;

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

STATIC_URL = "/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles")
```

To close your tag;

```
        {% load static %}
        <img src="{% static 'myapp/mini.jpg' %}" alt="My image"/>
```